# CSS z-index behaving strangely in my Rails 5 application

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I am using Rails 5 with SASS + Bootstrap and I have the following CSS code:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat');

body {

  background: #fff image-url('noise.png');

  div.site-top {

    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 178px;
    background: #fff image-url('logo01.jpg') no-repeat;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 3px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 5px 3px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow:         0px 5px 3px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);

    div.main-title {

      padding: 0px 0px 0px 290px;
      font-family: 'Dancing Script';
      font-size: 60px;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #fccf00;
      text-shadow: 3px 3px 2px rgba(150, 150, 150, 1);

      div.secondary-title {

        margin-top: -17px;
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 35px;
        font-family: 'Montserrat';
        font-size: 22px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #49840c;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(150, 150, 150, 1);

      }

    }

    div.top-menu {

      margin: 25px 0px 0px 0px;
      text-align: right;

      height: 54px;

      ul {

        margin: 0px 47.5px 0px 47.5px;
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;

        li {


          float: right;
          list-style-type: none;
          padding: 15px 40px 14px 0px;

          a {

            color: #666;
            font-size: 18px;
            font-weight: bold;

          }

          a:hover {

            text-decoration: none;
            color: #333;

          }

        }

      }

    }

  }

  div.container {

    z-index: -5;

    div.site-body {

      padding: 198px 20px 140px 20px;
      background-color: #fff;

      div.woman-from-fifties {

        float: left;
        height: 350px;
        background: #fff image-url('wff2.jpg') no-repeat;

      }

    }

  }

}
```

which works with this `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Clean House Serviços Domésticos</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="site-top">
      <div class="main-title">
        Clean House
        <div class="secondary-title">
          Serviços Domésticos
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="top-menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/clientes">Clientes</a></li>        
          <li><a href="/fale_conosco">Fale conosco</a></li>        
          <li><a href="/localizacao">Localização</a></li>        
          <li><a href="/sobre_nos">Sobre nós</a></li>        
          <li><a href="/">Homepage</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="container">
      <div class="site-body clearfix">
        <div class="site-content">
          <%= yield %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and this `app/views/website/index.html.erb`

```
<div class="col-md-4 woman-from-fifties">
</div>
<div class="col-md-8">
  <div class="well">
    teste
  </div>
</div>
```

to generate a page like in this image

[image]

It all works fine until I scrool down the page and see the Bootstrap `wells` in the lower part, which has `z-index: -5` as you may see, end up covering my upper banner as you may see in this image:

[image]

I really don't understand what is happening. As far as I am concerned, all elements inserted in this area with `z-index: -5` should be below the upper part.

Could someone explain what am I doing wrong?

Comment: increase the `z-index` of header greater than the content

Comment: I really thought this `z-index: -5` would be inherited by all elements inside it. It worked when I made `z-index: 5` in the upper part. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Would you please post as an answer for me to accept it?

Comment: I am glad to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this will help you try with this

```
div.site-top {
 z-index:999;
}

div.container {
 position:relative;
 z-index:9;
}
```